# How to alter mesh vertex colors/UVs at runtime?

Tags: godot

The situation is, I have a large MeshInstance2D of a hex grid, with each hex vertex UV or color being set when the mesh is created by the MeshDataTool. I want to be able to alter this mesh at runtime, the specific feature I'm implementing is a map editor. I've tried using the MeshDataTool to create from surface, altering the appropriate vertex colors or UVs with the set vertex UV function, and then committing to surface. This works for the specific hex I am painting but all the other hexes appear to be reset and the rest of the grid is black. How can I solve this problem with or without the MeshDataTool?

EDIT: Problem fixed, accidently was adding an extra surface to the ArrayMesh somewhere along the way. I do still have a question tho, is there a way to do this more efficiently with vertex shaders so I don't have to rebake the mesh every time? IE Could I control the vertex UVs individually (according to what triangle they belong to -> type of hex they represent) in this way?

Comment: Please, could you set a code sample, to get more context

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso I've made some progress in what I wanted to do but hit another roadblock lol. New problem is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574309/trouble-with-shaders (with code and explanatory picture). If you could take a look that would be aweomse!